# how to set specific source port

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, port

I'm using Spring's `RestTemplate` class to get XML from a web service outside my organisation.

Due to a change in local firewall rules, I need to specify a specific source port in my HTTP requests. Now I can't find anything in the [api](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html), on stackoverflow or any tutorial on how to do this.

Is this not possible?

More generally, in descriptions online, I have found that using a specific source port was generally done with UDP based connections/applications. Is this something that is not usually done with TCP?

(I really don't think it helps, but here's the code snippet, as asked by a commenter below):

```
MyRequest request = new MyRequest(); //whole thing done via jackson
RestTemplate templ = new RestTemplate();
this.serviceUrl = String.format("%s:%d", properties.getServiceUrl()
properties.getServicePort());
ExptectedResponse response = templ.postForObject(serviceUrl, request, ExptectedResponse.class);
```

Comment: append the port after url . Show the code

Comment: Hey, I added some code. Appending the port after the url is what I do already. However, this changes the DESTINATION port, not the source port. Still, thankful for any help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source port of a TCP connection is chosen at random from the ephemeral port range 49152-65535. TCP port ranges are shown here: [RFC 6056 - Ephemeral Ports](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6056#section-2)

> "The dynamic port range defined by IANA consists of the 49152-65535
> range, and is meant for the selection of ephemeral ports."

The port selection process differs depending on the operating system being used. This is much lower level than a typical Java application and therefore is out of your applications control.

Technically you can could force the OS to select a specified port, but as I mentioned is OS specific and breaks the classic portability of a Java application. There is a good post on Super User that talks about this subject [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1118735/how-are-source-ports-determined-and-how-can-i-force-it-to-use-a-specific-port).

I would suggest talking to the department that made the firewall change and see if they can allow outbound connections from normal port range.

Comment: Thanks! I thought so. I read the superuser post, but wasn't quite sure. As far as I can tell, the superuser post just talks about restricting the range of source ports to choose from, so if I have several programmes on it that connect via HTTP, it doesn't really help me...