# How to limit access of RestController method to specific clients

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

Client Application with the below mentioned server configuration in *application.properties* sends request to my application using restTemplate:

```
server.address=localhost
server.port=8081
```

My application knows the client's IP Address and port.

**How to check the request received by my application is from this specific client?**

I have tried to get the client's port using `HttpServletRequest request -> request.getRemotePort()` but It gives me random port numbers

Comment: do want get the remote client ip and port?

Comment: Yes. It's needed to limit access for some actions. Only clients with specific IP+port could execute some methods

Comment: remote client make use a  new random port to connect your server,so i think use ip and port is not suitable

Comment: But how can I give an access only for applications with specific ip+port if I have a list of ip+port client addresses?

Comment: If I check only IP it  can be not safe. Someone could deploy their app on the same server and get an access

Comment: refe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283942/how-to-set-specific-source-port) for why client select random port and how to select fixed port.if you want use ip and port for safe,i think you can use other method like token.

Comment: Probably you may control this on a LAN. Any other connection you need authorization by authentification (user/pass or similiar).

Comment: By client, do you mean some specific IP address/hosts or some users of your application?

Comment: @uneq95 indeed my application is distributed service with many nodes. They can send requests each other and specify headers. But clients could know this header and make my data invalid. Therefore I think I could check ip+port to know that this request is from one of my nodes. This way even if user would know this "secret" header, they couldn't abuse it

Comment: But now I think that it's impossible and I should add authorization for it

Comment: @Donatello I think use authorization is a better method,but iwhen client make a socket to connect you server and the client explicit bind to a local address,the server can get ip and port,but it's not a good way.

Comment: @Donatello : You can achieve using IP Whitelisting on your server also if you know your consumer then establish a SSL mutual authentication channel, both parties will share cert in order to make a secure channel. Industry standards as well you know.